# Split column on condition in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

The data frame I am working on has a column named "Phone" and I want to split in on **/** or **,** in a way such that I get the data frame as shown below in separate columns. For example, the first row is **0674-2537100/101** and I want to split it on "/" into two columns having values as **0674-2537100** and **0674-2537101**.

Input:

```
+-------------------------------+
|      Phone                    |
+-------------------------------+
|  0674-2537100/101             |
|  0674-2725627                 |
|  0671 – 2647509               |
|  2392229                      |
|  2586198/2583361              |
|  0663-2542855/2405168         |
|  0674 – 2563832/0674-2590796  |
|  0671-6520579/3200479         |
+-------------------------------+
```

Output:

```
+-----------------------------------+
|    Phone          |   Phone1      |
+-----------------------------------+
|  0674-2537100     |  0674-2537101 |
|  0674-2725627     |               |
|  0671 – 2647509   |               |
|  2392229          |               |
|  2586198          |  2583361      |
|  0663-2542855     |  0663-2405168 |
|  0674 – 2563832   |  0674-2590796 |
|  0671-6520579     |  0671-3200479 |
+-----------------------------------+
```

Here I came up with a solution where I can take out the length of strings on both sides of the separator(/). Take out their difference. Copy the substring from the first column from character position [:difference-1] to the second column.

So far my progress is,

```
df['Phone'] = df['Phone'].str.replace(' ', '')

df['Phone'] = df['Phone'].str.replace('–', '-')

df[['Phone','Phone1']] = df['Phone'].str.split("/",expand=True)

df["Phone1"].fillna(value=np.nan, inplace=True)

m2 = (df["Phone1"].str.len() < 12) & (df["Phone"].str.len() > 7) 

m3 = df["Phone"].str.len() - df["Phonenew"].str.len()

df.loc[m2, "Phone1"] = df["Phone"].str[:m3-1] + df["Phonenew"]
```

It gives an error and the column has only nan values after I run this. PLease help me out here.

Comment: Please provide the example code in a copy paste method, we can't copy an image.

Comment: Also, are you going to have multiple '/' in a row?

Comment: @Thymen Please find an example I hope its more accurate now.

Comment: @maverick6912 it can have multiple '/' or even ',' in a row. It is a huge data set and this is only a sample of it. Also, your solution is good but I want the output to look a bit different. Please check now.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you're only going to have 2 '/' in the 'Phone' column. Here's what you can do:

```py
'''
This fucntion takes in rows of a dataframe as an input and returns row with appropriate values.
'''
def split_phone_number(row):
    split_str=row['Phone'].split('/')    
#     Considering that you're only going to have 2 or lesser values, update
#     the passed row's columns with appropriate values.
    if len(split_str)>1:
        row['Phone']=split_str[0]
        row['Phone1']=split_str[1]        
    else:
        row['Phone']=split_str[0]
        row['Phone1']=''
#    Return the updated row.
    return row

# Making a dummy dataframe.
d={'Phone':['0674-2537100/101','0674-257349','0671-257349','257349','257349/100','101/100','5688343/438934']}
dataFrame= pd.DataFrame(data=d)
# Considering you're only going to have one extra column. adding that column to dataframe.
dataFrame=dataFrame.assign(Phone1=['' for i in range(dataFrame.shape[0])])
# applying the split_phone_number function to dataframe.
dataFrame=dataFrame.apply(split_phone_number,axis=1)
# Prinitng dataframe.
print(dataFrame)
```

Input:

```
+---------------------+
|               Phone |
+---------------------+
| 0  0674-2537100/101 |
| 1       0674-257349 |
| 2       0671-257349 |
| 3            257349 |
| 4        257349/100 |
| 5           101/100 |
| 6    5688343/438934 |
+---------------------+
```

Output:

```
+----------------------------+
|    Phone            Phone1 |
+----------------------------+
| 0  0674-2537100     101    |
| 1   0674-257349            |
| 2   0671-257349            |
| 3        257349            |
| 4        257349     100    |
| 5           101     100    |
| 6       5688343  438934    |
+----------------------------+
```

For further reading:

[dataframe.apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

### Hope this helps. Cheers!